# Artificial Intelligence or Bot in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby, algorithm, ruby-on-rails-4, artificial-intelligence, bots

This is more of a vague/general question, so for that I do apologize in advance.  I'm building a simple Rails app with Twilio integration that will allow users to send messages such as "how are you" and receive a quasi-intelligent response back from the app such as, "Good, how about yourself, John?".

I have everything wired up and it works but I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction of writing an algorithm in Ruby that would make this "bot" smarter.  Right now I'm using a pretty straight forward if/elsif/else chain to parse the payload and deliver the proper response but this does not seem maintainable once I get past 5-10 keywords.

Would I be better off with a case statement (at least for readability) or is there a better OOP design pattern that would help me match my keywords and deliver a certain response?

Comment: You can start with https://wit.ai/getting-started

Comment: If you are comfortable at the moment with simple keyword / response pairs, the next logical step is to store those in a database (SQLite is just fine for this).  Then you can have multiple possible responses per keyword that will let you randomize the responses a little.

Comment: I recently made a gem for wit.ai, (@MaximFilippov suggested trying this) an external nlp service, called [wit_bot](http://bensites.com/wit_bot/). It has support for bots out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. If you want to write a real chat bot, prepare for 5+ years of reading papers on neural networks. Might as well just give up now :)

However, if you reduce your requirements (make the bot recognize only a few selected keywords, with predefined response(s) for each), then a simple dictionary approach could suffice.

You're right, storing the dictionary in code is not scalable. It's better to store the knowledge in a data file (YAML, JSON or whatever you prefer) or a database. Then your code will load the file and will be able to look up responses by keywords.

Something like this:

```
def reply(input)
  # you load this from a storage, so that when you add new keywords,
  # your code doesn't have to be touched.
  knowledge = [
    { keyword: 'how are you', response: 'Good, how about yourself, %{name}?' },
    { keyword: 'bye', response: 'Ciao!' },
  ]

  response = knowledge.detect do |pair|
    input.downcase.include?(pair[:keyword].downcase)
  end

  response && response[:response]
end

reply('How are you doing, machine?') # => "Good, how about yourself, %{name}?"
reply('gotta go, bye') # => "Ciao!"
```

Comment: Good point for neural networks

Comment: Thanks for confirming what I had suspected.  This is more of an experiment for me adding some intelligence to my app.  I think persisting the K/V pairs (keywords/responses) in YAML or in a DB would probably be my best move.  Otherwise the class will become a huge monstrosity and not maintainable.  I really appreciate your advice and guidance on this.